# python lx module to create the file

Tags: python, scripting

I am working on **MODO** scripts in **python**.I created my script as follow:

```
#python

import lx
import sys

layers = lx.evalN("query layerservice layers ? all")
oFile   = open('myfile.txt','w')

for layer in layers:

     lx.out('Hello World!')


     layerName = lx.eval1("query layerservice layer.name ? %s"%layer)
     lx.out("Layer Name : %s" %layerName)

     and so on.....
```

when i run this script in **MODO**,rest everything works fine for me.I wanted to create one text file at same time and perform write operation on it.but the code

```
oFile   = open('myfile.txt','w')
```

do not create text file.So i cannot proceed further.
How do i create my file and perform write operation on it.???
Thanx in advance.

Comment: yes..it creates in C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Luxology\modo\601_sp1 path....u know how to change locatiom??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are creating the file in an unexpected location.

You can either pass a full path to the `open` call, or use `os.chdir(...)` to change the directory in which files will be opened.

Comment: thanx i changed the location:)